# mobx observer suddenly not rerendering when observable changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mobx

My app stopped updating on observable changes and I'm going crazy trying to figure out why.  The code below shows only "Counter: 5" on the screen even though the console shows that it is updating.    The relevant parts of package.json are:

```js
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "mobx": "^6.0.4",
    "mobx-react": "^7.0.5",
    "react": "17.0.0",
    "react-dom": "17.0.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-mobx": "^2.0.0",
    "react-app-rewire-yaml": "^1.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.1"
  }
}
```

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css"
import { inject, observer, Provider } from "mobx-react";
import { observable } from "mobx";

class TestModel
{
    @observable counter = 5;
    start() {
        setInterval(() => {this.counter++; console.log(this.counter)}, 1000);
    }
}

@inject("testModel")
@observer 
class TestPage extends React.Component<{testModel?: TestModel}> 
{
    render() {
        return <div><h1>Counter: {this.props.testModel.counter}</h1></div>
    }
}

const theTestModel = new TestModel();
theTestModel.start();

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider testModel={theTestModel}> 
        <TestPage />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

EDIT:

Turns out I needed to call makeObservable(this) in the constructor of my TestModel, plus I had to pull out the side effect into an action context like this:

```
@action incrementCounter = () => {
    this.counter++; 
    console.log(this.counter)
}

start() {
    setInterval(this.incrementCounter, 1000);
}
```

Comment: You did *not* need to create a class field for `incrementCounter`. It's possible to wrap functions in place: `setInterval(action(() => {this.counter++; console.log(this.counter)}), 1000)`. It's actually more practical to do it this way because you get access to the variables from the scope of the parent function. Also you can just disable this requirement for actions `configure({enforceActions: 'never'})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Since `mobx@6.0.0` decorators are not enough](https://mobx.js.org/enabling-decorators.html#enabling-decorators-). You have to make your class observable manually with [`makeObservable`](https://mobx.js.org/observable-state.html#makeobservable) as well.

```js
import { observable, makeObservable } from "mobx";

class TestModel {
    @observable counter = 5;

    constructor() {
        makeObservable(this);
    }

    start() {
        setInterval(() => {this.counter++; console.log(this.counter)}, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!!  PS: To be fully compliant, I also had to pull out the counter++ into an @action decorated function.