# component doesn't re-render when store udates mobx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I made a store, with one field and one action. However, when the event that triggers the action is triggered, the storage itself is not updated, and the component is not re-rendered.

store:

```
configure({ isolateGlobalState: true });

class CallStore {
  @observable call;

  constructor() {
    this.call = false;
  }

  @action turnOnCall = (isTrue) => {
    return this.call = isTrue;
  }
}

const callStore = new CallStore();

export default callStore;
```

Сomponent that needs to be updated:

```
 const App = (props) => {
  return props.call ? (   
    <main>
      <VideoFormContainer />
      <Video />
    </main>
  ) : (
    <main>
      <VideoFormContainer />
    </main>
  );
};

 export default App;
```

The container of this component:

```
    const AppContainer = inject('callStore')(observer(({ callStore }) => (
      <App call={callStore.call} />
    )));
    
export default AppContainer;
```

Сomponent that calls the action

```
import callStore from '../../stores/callStore';

    const someComponent = () => {
    return (
        <button className="header__form-button" onClick={callStore.turnOnCall(true)} type="submit">Join</button>
    )
}
```

Comment: Are you using MobX 6 or later versions? If yes, [have you seen this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65851639/mobx-observer-suddenly-not-rerendering-when-observable-changes)? You also want to give a function to `onClick`, not invoke it directly on render. I.e. `onClick={() => callStore.turnOnCall(true)}`

Comment: You're damn right. I'm using version 6.0.4, thanks for this link it helped!
And about the transfer of the function, I just made a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the absence of makeObservable in store.

```
constructor() {
   makeObservable(this);
}
```